# Buddypress and a wordpress child theme?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

Ok I’m lost I’ve read lot’s of threads concerning how to to apply a buddypress child theme and now I’ve just read: http://bpdevel.wordpress.com/2013/11/13/the-future-of-the-bp-default-theme/
which seems to say that buddypress no longer supports child themes….
I’m really lost how do i go about apply changes to buddypress’s default pages in a manner that will hold up for future updates and not screw with my parent theme…
I currently have /wp-content/themes/child-theme/buddypress/COPY FROM buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/ in my child theme but it fails to recognize the theme files unless i move them up to the child theme folder… and when i do it then rips out the css and js for the buddypress pages….
How do i go about setting up buddypress’s theme files in my child theme.
Kind reagrds
Chris.
P.S I’ve also read :

http://codex.buddypress.org/themes/theme-compatibility-1-7/template-hierarchy/

http://codex.buddypress.org/themes/theme-compatibility-1-7/a-quick-look-at-1-7-theme-compatibility/

which just confused me further…
Do i copy over the bp-legacy folder if i do won’t this be discontinued…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BuddyPress now utilises a template hierarchy in the same way as WordPress does.

If you do nothing to a standard WordPress theme, BuddyPress will use the `page.php` template to display BuddyPress content. However, you can style BuddyPress differently to `page.php` and that's where the *template hierarchy* comes in.

To introduce your own custom BuddyPress templates, start by creating a new folder called 'buddypress' inside your WordPress theme. So your folder structure will look like this: `/wp-content/themes/your-theme/buddypress/`. All BuddyPress templates that you create from now on are contained within the `/buddypress/` folder.

**EXAMPLE:** Use a custom template to display the `example.com/members/username/activity/mentions/` page.

*If at any point you need more info, you can refer to the BuddyPress [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.buddypress.org/themes/theme-compatibility-1-7/template-hierarchy/) article for an in-depth explanation.*

**Step 1:** Create the folders:

```
/buddypress/members/single/
```

**Step 2:** Create the file:

```
/buddypress/members/single/index-action-{action}.php
```

*Note:* In this example, `{action}` will be `mentions`. If you were creating a template to style the favorites page then `{action}` will be `favorites`.

So you should have:

```
/buddypress/members/single/index-action-mentions.php
```

That's all there is to it. Whatever you put in your `index-action-mentions.php` file will display on the `example.com/members/username/activity/mentions/` page.

Comment: SO where do i get the current files buddypress is using to move them over to the child-theme i'm using?

Comment: Do you mean where are files such as `index-action-mentions.php`? The key to using the template hierarchy is to understand there are no such files. You have to create them yourself. If you don't create them, BuddyPress will use the `page.php` template that is provided by 'most' WordPress themes.

Comment: Yeah i relaized after i asked the question... Thank you for takng the time to answer..